# zombie.js - execute javascript in html page

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, zombie.js

I'm trying to scrape pages from this site: http://www.stubhub.com/beatleshow-tickets/b-beatleshow-las-vegas-planet-hollywood-resort-and-casino-30-4-2014-4436775/

What I need is the ticket prices. They are in a div with class p_cont. But they are loaded later. So what I need is to execute the code in the html page to build up the whole page as if in a browser.

I tried the module zombie, but all I get is this error:

```
jQuery is not defined ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at <anonymous>:4:404
    at Contextify.sandbox.run (/home/koem/coding/node/stubhub/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/lib/contextify.js:12:24)
    at DOMWindow.window._evaluate (/home/koem/coding/node/stubhub/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/window.js:188:25)
    at Object.HTML.languageProcessors.javascript (/home/koem/coding/node/stubhub/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/scripts.js:23:21)
    at define.proto._eval (/home/koem/coding/node/stubhub/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level2/html.js:1480:47)
    at loaded (/home/koem/coding/node/stubhub/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/scripts.js:74:23)
    at /home/koem/coding/node/stubhub/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level2/html.js:76:20
    at Object.item.check (/home/koem/coding/node/stubhub/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level2/html.js:345:11)
    at Object.item.check (/home/koem/coding/node/stubhub/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level2/html.js:348:23)
    at Object.item.check (/home/koem/coding/node/stubhub/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level2/html.js:348:23)
```

my code:

```
var
  url = "http://www.stubhub.com/beatleshow-tickets/b-beatleshow-las-vegas-planet-hollywood-resort-and-casino-30-4-2014-4436775/",
  Browser = require("zombie"),
  assert = require("assert");

browser = new Browser();
browser.visit(url, function() {
  console.log(browser.html(".p_cont"));
  console.log("done");
});
```

Any ideas? Is it possible to make nodejs behave like a browser? Or is this possible with Java or other languages / libraries?

Best,
Koem